# dlopen for dylib, .framework

Tags: ios, dylib

I am doing for enterprise app and I am studying about dlopen because I need to download code and run in runtime. (like sub-module).

[Calling dlopen on ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578957/calling-dlopen-on-ios)

[Download and execute iOS code dynamically at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187911/download-and-execute-ios-code-dynamically-at-runtime)

I start to confuse about that because some open .dylib and some open .framework.

I try to load from resource directory and hModule is always nil.

```
NSString *dlPath = @"StaticLibrary.dylib";//i try with complete path and it is not okay also

const char* cdlpath = [dlPath UTF8String];
void* hModule = dlopen(cdlpath, RTLD_LAZY);
```

I download from url and try like this too.

```
    const char *cString = [filePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    void *uikit = dlopen(cString, RTLD_GLOBAL);
    id (*FunctionName)() = dlsym(uikit, "helloWorldFromStaticLibrary");
    FunctionName();
    dlclose(uikit);
    //my cString is "/Users/khantthulinn/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/04F2B44A-B78E-4400-98B7-EF6AA8352646/data/Containers/Data/Application/63E7D709-F140-4AF1-A4F5-475454B347FE/Library/Caches/StaticLibrary.dylib"
```

I just don't know why my dlopen is always nil. Some people in stackoverflow said that I need to sign with same certificate. I have tried also. But it is not okay. How shall I do?

Comment: And what does `dlerror()` tell you when `dlopen()` fails?

Comment: Can I log like this? const char *dlErr = dlerror(); When I po dlerror(), it is <nil>.

Comment: and that's inside `if (uikit == NULL) { ... }`?

Comment: yes. It is like that. I now po dlErr and I saw this. 
"dlopen(/Users/khantthulinn/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/04F2B44A-B78E-4400-98B7-EF6AA8352646/data/Containers/Data/Application/EE454318-5521-49CE-80E6-2DF3361B209E/Library/Caches/StaticLibrary.dylib, 8): no suitable image found.  Did find:\n\t/Users/khantthulinn/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/04F2B44A-B78E-4400-98B7-EF6AA8352646/data/Containers/Data/Application/EE454318-5521-49CE-80E6-2DF3361B209E/Library/Caches/StaticLibrary.dylib: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x20 0x3C 0x21 0x44 0x4F 0x43 0x54 0x59"

Comment: OK, so there is your answer. The file isn't a dynamic library; it's a file that starts `" <!DOCTY"` (i.e. 95% chance an HTML file).  So your download code is borked.

Comment: ohh...my bad. Now it show me new error. How shall I do?
 "dlsym(0x7facca41fee0, helloWorldFromStaticLibrary): symbol not found"

Comment: Are you sure the symbol is visible?  Run `nm` on the library and see if you can see it (it will have the type `T`, I believe).

Comment: Could you please guide me how to run nm? I have uploaded my library to here. http://www.mediafire.com/download/ltcb23rf9lskt81/StaticLibrary_2.zip
I wrote like this in .h. http://tinypic.com/r/34ecisz/9 It shall be visible?

Comment: I am not at my Mac at the moment so I am unable to help.  I'm sure you will find plenty of help if you search online.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108464/discussion-between-khant-thu-linn-and-trojanfoe).

Comment: @KhantThuLinn did this work? I've got a similar use case, and I'm having trouble getting the dylib to open with dlopen

Comment: sadly no. I give up on that.